# SQL Group By Query With Specific First Row

Tags: sql

I'm using this query to pull information about companies and their scores from a ms sql database.

```
  SELECT company, avg(score) AS Value FROM Responses where id=12 group by company
```

This is the result

```
 |   COMPANY     | VALUE |

 |: ------------ | ------:|

 | Competitor A  | 6.09   |

 | Competitor B  | 5.70   |

 | Other Brand   | 5.29   |

 | Your Brand    | 6.29   |
```

What I need is a query that will put one company that I will specify in the first position (in this case, the company is Your Brand) and then order the rest by the company like this.

```
 |   COMPANY     | VALUE |

 |: ------------ | -----:|

 | Your Brand    | 6.29   |

 | Competitor A  | 6.09   |

 | Competitor B  | 5.70   |

 | Other Brand   | 5.29   |
```

Comment: Use a case expression in the ORDER BY to put Your Brand first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jarlh has suggested, use a `CASE` expression to order:

```
SELECT company, AVG(score) AS Value
FROM Responses
WHERE id = 12
GROUP BY company
ORDER BY CASE company WHEN 'Your Brand' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         AVG(score) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks..that query results in no values returned (no errors either). Any idea why?

Comment: No ..my mistake...this works great